# Display selected amount of records from database

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a page that displays records from a database, sorted by their jobs. So the database holds different kind of persons with different jobs. For example, on the page "teacher" I just want to display all the teachers, not the other persons. I want to have 3 persons on a page and a button "previous" and "next" beneath it. If an user clicks the next-button I want the next 3 records to be shown. When the user reaches the last records, I need the next-button to disappear. Same goes for "previous".

What I have so far:

This piece of code creates a value named startrow.

```
if (!isset($_GET['startrow']) or !is_numeric($_GET['startrow'])) {
  //give the value of the starting row 0 because nothing was found in URL
  $startrow = 0;
  //otherwise take the value from the URL
} else {
  $startrow = (int)$_GET['startrow'];
}
```

The query I have:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE jobs='teacher' LIMIT $startrow, 3")or
die(mysql_error());
$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalJobs FROM $tbl_name WHERE jobs='teacher'";

$result_count = mysql_query($sql2);
$count = mysql_fetch_array($result_count);
```

I created the $count for the if / else function in the next part (the part that doesn't seem to work the way I want it to):

```
if ($startrow < $count )
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.($startrow+3).'">Next</a>';

$prev = $startrow - 3;
//only print a "Previous" link if a "Next" was clicked
if ($prev >= 0)
    echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.$prev.'">Previous</a>';
```

So the previous-button seems to work the way it should. The next doesn't. I've created the

```
if ($startrow < $count)
```

so basicly, if the value of startrow is smaller than the total number of records, it puts a next-button. But if I test this, it displays the next-button anyhow, no matter the value of startrow.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) returns an array containing the count, not the value itself. Use `$count['TotalJobs']` instead.

Also, you shouldn't use the mysql extension anymore, instead use [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo) or [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/mysqli).

### Edit

---

You can change:

```
$count = mysql_fetch_array($result_count);
```

to

```
$countArr = mysql_fetch_array($result_count);
$count    = $countArr['TotalJobs'];
```

Comment: so, where exactly do I put this `$count['TotalJobs']`? Do I delete this whole `mysql_fetch_array`? Because I've tested just that part and it does return the number of records.